# Duplicating a site using MSM with Low Variables

Tags: multi-site-manager, low-variables, low

I need to be able to duplicate a site as a new MSM site and keep my Low Variables settings, values, titles, descriptions, field types, etc.

Is there a solution. I would hate to have to recreate 80 of these every time I need a new MSM site.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't an automated way of doing this for many major third party add-ons.

For example, I recently had to branch out a few channels from a site into its own MSM site. One of the channels had a Matrix field. In that matrix field was an Assets column. Oh boy, was that fun. I had to make a template (pure PHP) that functioned as an import script from the main site to the new MSM site. I learned a bunch along the way; I had to reverse engineer the Assets add-on database schema to get it correct. The benefit is that I now have a solid script for that process.

Sorry, not much of an answer, more of an experience recounting. I will have to do that again for sure (we have a stupidly huge site that we are breaking out to MSM piece by piece), so it was worth getting right.

Comment: I played around with the database and exported the table associated with the low variables.  I may be able to do some with with that and create some type of process that I can import in another set of variables but it's going to get tricky as I continue to add MSM sites.  It seems like it would be a standard functionality to be able to do this.  I guess I'm hoping someone has the magic wand.